# Grooveshark.com like search results filter

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

In my webpage, I am having a table that is being pulled from the database. I would like this table to be filtered dynamically when the user types a keyword in the search box. Similar functionality is being implemented by [Grooveshark.com](http://Grooveshark.com)

What would be the best way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch

I use it and its well made and simple to use.

Comment: This one looks close but it is not actually filtering the search results. I want it to filter as I am typing the keyword in the search box.
If you have used it, could you give me the link which has a live example?

Comment: I use it on a private site, but it filters each table row live as you type

Comment: The demo provided in the plugin doesnt work actually. But it works in my website!

Answer (score 0):

What your wanting is called an autocomplete, i don't know what ajax framework your using (jquery, prototype, mootools, etc..) but jquery has a pretty flexible one built into it. ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ ) take a look at there examples on the right, your might want to pay close attention to the "remote with caching". If your not using query then i'm sure if you google the words "ajax search autocomplete" you'll find a plugin for nearly any framework. (substitute ajax with your preferred ajax framework)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am aware about autocomplete. What I need actually is a filter. I have search results already on my page, now I wanna filter it further, narrow it down. I believe you will get a demo of this feature on Grooveshark. Search for a particular band, then in the same search box, search a song of that band.